# Linq search not returning all entries

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Guys i have two problems... firstly i have a linq query search that queries name and surname and returns  the results from the db.  eg .if i search John it will return John travolta which is perfect (my problem being) if i search john travolta the name and surname together it will find no result?... help.

Problem number 2: how do i clear the results of the search when i search again? because when i search the second time the results of the previous search is

```
public class SearchResults
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Surname { get; set; }

            public SearchResults(string name, string surname)
            {
                Name = name;
                Surname = surname;
            }



 protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string search = txtSearch.Text.ToLower().TrimEnd();
            lsSearchResults = null;
            lsSearchResults = new List<SearchResults>();
            Repeater1.DataSource = null;
            lsSearchResults.Clear();
            Repeater1.DataSource = "";
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtSearch.Text))
            {
              lblResults.Text = "Please enter a password & Em@ilAddress";

                lsSearchResults.Clear();

                return;
            }

        else
        {
            var found = (from User in myDB.Memberships
                         where User.Name.ToLower().Contains(txtSearch.Text.ToLower()) ||
                         User.Surname.ToLower().Contains(txtSearch.Text.ToLower())
                         select new { User.Name, User.Surname });

            // validates items in search query if Exist
            if (!ChillZARdev.App_Code.Utilities.IsEmpty(found))
            {
                foreach (var user in found)
                {
                    lsSearchResults.Add(new SearchResults(user.Name, user.Surname));
                    // ls.Add(user.Name + " " + user.Surname);

                    // Response.Write(user);
                }
                Repeater1.DataSource = lsSearchResults;

                Repeater1.DataBind();

             }
          }
```

Comment: nothing to do with your problem, but do consider writing your code this way : lsSearchResults = (from User ... select new SearchResults(User.Name, User.Surname)).ToList(); you'll avoid anonymous type instanciation and to browse your result twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var found = myDB.Memberships;
foreach(var word in txtSearch.Text)
{
    var word2=word;  //Must do this because word won't be right at execution
    found=found.Where(u=>u.Name.Contains(word2) || u.Surname.Contains(word2));
}
```

I've removed the .ToLower, because the columns should already be marked as being case insensitive, and will be unless you've either changed it directly, or the default culture of the database.

Comment: This will work for "John", "Travolta", "John Tavolta" and "Travolta John" and will do it all server-side rather than client-side.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the extra .ToLower checks when using LINQ to SQL/EF. It is necessary in LINQ to Objects, but not (most) databases.

Comment: Thank you so much robert this really helped a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Short solution would be to include firstname and surname together in the where clause:

```
var found = (from User in myDB.Memberships
             where User.Name.ToLower().Contains(txtSearch.Text.ToLower()) ||
             User.Surname.ToLower().Contains(txtSearch.Text.ToLower()) ||
             (User.Name + " " + User.Surname).ToLower().Contains(txtSearch.Text.ToLower())
```

However, this means a search for "Travolta john" wouldn't return any results.

If this matters you should split up the string by spaces, and search for each word.

```
List<string> searchSplit = txtSearch.Text.ToLower().Split(' ');

var found = (from User in myDB.Memberships
         where IsMatch(searchSplit, User)

private bool IsMatch(List<string> searchSplit, User User){
   return searchSplit.Count() ==
          searchSplit.Where(x => User.Name.ToLower().Contains(x) ||
                                 User.Surname.ToLower().Contains(x)).Count();
}
```

Ideally, as [Steve B has commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526532/linq-search-not-returning-all-entries#comment25486068_17526603), it would be best to implement a pre-built search engine which would require more tools for searching than a simple custom search would. But it depends on what your budget/requirements are.

Comment: This will implies that the user always use this format, with no extra space, same order and no typo error. I think the only way to properly handle the requirement is to implement a search engine (Lucene.Net? Solr.Net? SharePOint? Etc...) that will provide far more tools to search for data... but with a far more expensive solution

Comment: Thank you so much that worked very well...  Problem number two? how do i clear results after search

Comment: Thanks @SteveB I've added your comments to the answer.

Comment: hmmm... I think your approach means a search for "John Travolta" will return all people called "John" regardless of their surname, seems like an unexpected behavior from the end user... all depends on how you want it to work though

Comment: @musefan Your right, I've changed the logic of the IsMatch method so that every word in the split must match something.

Comment: Not sure why he used count here, it would seem if you really want to to this client side, you would be better off doing `return searchSplit.All(x=>User.Name.ToLower().Contains(x) || User.Surname.ToLower().Contains(x))` which will also perform a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of months back, i was having the same problem, i was using singleton design pattern and the root problem was with the cache..  and for both of your problems there is one solution - you can try to clean the cache of a LINQ to SQL DataContext and you can do that by following way

```
public static void ClearCache(this DataContext context) 
 { 
    const BindingFlags FLAGS = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic; 
    var method = context.GetType().GetMethod("ClearCache", FLAGS); 
    method.Invoke(context, null); 
 }
```

and you can call that method

```
   public void DoWork() 
     { 
        //do work... 
        dataContext.ClearCache(); 
       //do more work... 
     }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Microtechie i tried your code and sadly failed ill keep trying...  to solve this issue... i dont know if the problem is my repeater because the results are binded to a repear.